# In bot framework v4, how to implemente rating card with comment box and submit button

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have made a bot framework V4 using C#. I have made star rating in adaptive card but I need to add comment box and submit button in it,but my submit button is not working.In debugging mode its not hitting the any method of bot.Kindly help me. I am also attaching the code of my rating card having comment box and submit button in it.

```
 {
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
   {
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "size": "Medium",
  "weight": "Bolder",
  "color": "Accent",
  "text": "Rate your experience!"
    },
    {
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "separator": true,
  "text": "Please rate your experience! Your feedback is very appreciated and will help improve your 
  experience in the future. ",
  "wrap": true
},
  {
  "type": "ColumnSet",
  "spacing": "Medium",
  "columns": [
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "awful"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Awful"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "bad"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Bad"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "ok"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Ok"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "good"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Good"
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    },
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "data": "terrific"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Image",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "text": "Terrific"
        }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        }
      ]
     },
{
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "comment",
      "placeholder": "Add a comment",
      "isMultiline": true
    }
      ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.0",
       "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Ok",
      "data": "ok"
    }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Did you use the Adaptive Card designer for that or did you code it by yourself?

Comment: @ShivaniSingh What channel is this in? What do you mean by "In debugging mode its not hitting the any method of bot"? Adaptive Card submit actions should be found in `Activity.Value` instead of the normal `Activity.Text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your card JSON that you need to fix:

1. Your actions don't have titles.
2. You should make `data` an object instead of a string. String works, mostly, but is less consistent.

You can find/fix most errors with your card by copy/pasting your code [in the Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) and looking for errors:

[image]

I've recreated your card so that it works:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Rate your experience!",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "size": "Medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Please rate your experience! Your feedback is very appreciated and will help improve your experience in the future. ",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "altText": "",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "data": { "rating": "awful" },
                                "title": "awful"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "altText": "",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "data": { "rating": "bad" },
                                "title": "bad"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "altText": "",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "data": { "rating": "ok" },
                                "title": "ok"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "altText": "",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "data": { "rating": "good" },
                                "title": "good"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "altText": "",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Five-pointed_star.svg",
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "data": { "rating": "terrific" },
                                "title": "terrific"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Add a comment",
            "isMultiline": true,
            "id": "comment"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note, that the feedback will come in `Activity.Value.rating`

Comment: I've been wondering that about strings in "data" - thanks @mrichardson

Comment: On a separate note, but related to the original question, I haven't tested "selectAction". I assume it would send a response back immediately to the bot? If so, then in a case like this, how would OP deal with the user hitting the "Ok" button, because the comments box and the button are lower down on the card, and the user would likely just hit a star rating first? Would it come back as 2 separate calls to the bot? If so, there'd be no way, as it stands, to tie them back together. Perhaps all the Action.Submits need an "id" property so that the state could be stored after each Submit?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow [Strings should work](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/), but I had trouble making it work when testing this. When the OK button gets clicked, it sends whatever is in any `inputs` (just the text box in this case) as well as anything in the `data` property of the `Submit.Action`. So yes, it would be two separate calls if they 1) click the star, and 2) click Submit. The ID property is definitely a recommendation.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, is it possible to apply animation when a user hovers over the stars, for example, see this link, https://codepen.io/ashdurham/pen/HBxLK, you will notice as the user hovers from the 1st to the 4th star, stars 1 to 4 get selected. And if the user hovers back left to say the second star then the 3rd and 4th star get deselected. I had asked that question yesterday in a different thread not realising this existed, see  [Star rating input using Adaptive cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954704/star-rating-input-using-adaptive-cards)

Comment: @VenkatSrinivasan There is nothing native to WebChat or Adaptive Cards that allows for this. You'd have to do some *very* fancy CSS to make it work, which 1) will be a little extra difficult because I don't believe it's easy to select that element with classes/ids, and 2) it will only work in Web Chat.

Comment: how to change the color of stars when selecting the rating?