# Star rating input using Adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am looking to develop an Adaptive card that will take a user input value ranging from 1 to 5 depending on the number of stars the user selects.

I also would like to apply animation as the user hovers over the stars. For example if the user hovers through from left to right to the 4th star then I would like stars 1 to 4 selected. Similarly, if the user hovers back left to the 2nd star then I would like the 3rd and 4th star deselected. See the link below for an example.

However, given adaptive cards are purely declarative (i.e. no code is allowed) is it possible to develop one? If so please can you point me in the right direction?

See link below for an example of how I would like this presented to a user (to be clear using Adaptive cards),

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ashdurham/pen/HBxLK) - A code pen by Ash Durham

**HTML**

```
 <span class="rating_stars rating_0">
  <span class='s' data-low='0.5' data-high='1'><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  <span class='s' data-low='1.5' data-high='2'><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  <span class='s' data-low='2.5' data-high='3'><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  <span class='s' data-low='3.5' data-high='4'><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  <span class='s' data-low='4.5' data-high='5'><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>

  <span class='r r0_5' data-rating='1' data-value='0.5'></span>
  <span class='r r1' data-rating='1' data-value='1'></span>
  <span class='r r1_5' data-rating='15' data-value='1.5'></span>
  <span class='r r2' data-rating='2' data-value='2'></span>
  <span class='r r2_5' data-rating='25' data-value='2.5'></span>
  <span class='r r3' data-rating='3' data-value='3'></span>
  <span class='r r3_5' data-rating='35' data-value='3.5'></span>
  <span class='r r4' data-rating='4' data-value='4'></span>
  <span class='r r4_5' data-rating='45' data-value='4.5'></span>
  <span class='r r5' data-rating='5' data-value='5'></span>
</span>

<div class="values">
  <div>
    <label>Rating</label><input type="text" id="rating" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Rating Value</label><input type="text" name="rating" id="rating_val" value="0" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info">
  <p>The above textboxes should be hidden fields, but have been made textboxes to display the values when you click.</p>
  <p>The 'Rating' value can be used for class/id based changes to this if wanting to use a background sprite to manage the stars instead.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .rating_stars {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #918f8f;
    position: relative;
}

.rating_stars span .fa, .rating_stars span.active-low .fa-star-o, .rating_stars span.active-high .fa-star-o{
    display: none;
}

.rating_stars span .fa-star-o{
    display: inline-block;
}

.rating_stars span.s.active-high .fa-star{
    display: inline-block; color: #feb645;
}

.rating_stars span.s.active-low .fa-star-half-o{
    display: inline-block; color: #feb645;
}

.rating_stars span.r {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    left: 0;
}

.rating_stars span.r.r0_5 {left:0px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r1 {left:10px; width: 11px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r1_5 {left:21px; width: 13px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r2 {left:34px; width: 12px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r2_5 {left:46px; width: 12px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r3 {left:58px; width: 11px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r3_5 {left:69px; width: 12px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r4 {left:81px; width: 12px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r4_5 {left:93px; width: 12px;}
.rating_stars span.r.r5 {left:105px; width: 12px;}

/* Just to make things look pretty ;) */
html, body {
  text-align: center; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #eee;
  background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}
label {width: 100px;display: inline-block; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px;}
input {width: 50px; text-align: center;}
.values {margin-top: 20px;}
.info {max-width: 500px; margin: 20px auto;}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.rating_stars span.r').hover(function() {
            // get hovered value
            var rating = $(this).data('rating');
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            $(this).parent().attr('class', '').addClass('rating_stars').addClass('rating_'+rating);
            highlight_star(value);
        }, function() {
            // get hidden field value
            var rating = $("#rating").val();
            var value = $("#rating_val").val();
            $(this).parent().attr('class', '').addClass('rating_stars').addClass('rating_'+rating);
            highlight_star(value);
        }).click(function() {
            // Set hidden field value
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            $("#rating_val").val(value);

            var rating = $(this).data('rating');
            $("#rating").val(rating);

            highlight_star(value);
        });

        var highlight_star = function(rating) {
            $('.rating_stars span.s').each(function() {
                var low = $(this).data('low');
                var high = $(this).data('high');
                $(this).removeClass('active-high').removeClass('active-low');
                if (rating >= high) $(this).addClass('active-high');
                else if (rating == low) $(this).addClass('active-low');
            });
        }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a question very similar to this just yesterday - see [In bot framework v4, how to implemente rating card with comment box and submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929544/in-bot-framework-v4-how-to-implemente-rating-card-with-comment-box-and-submit-b). Very important - note the comments below the answer as we had an important discussion that might also be applicable to your scenario

Comment: Thanks @HiltonGiesenow. Perhaps I should have been clearer, my bad. I am looking for the animation in particular as the user hovers over the stars. If you are able to navigate to the link https://codepen.io/ashdurham/pen/HBxLK you will notice as the user hovers over the 4th star, stars 1 to 4 get selected. And if the user hover left to say the second star then the 3rd and 4th star get deselected.

Comment: Sure thing. If you feel the answer helped, please mark it as such. Good luck implemeting!

Comment: oh, I just see your comment now. That's not possible right now with adaptive cards, I'm afraid.